# How do I synthesize sounds with CoreAudio on iPhone/Mac

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, core-audio

I'd like to play a synthesised sound in an iPhone. Instead of using a pre-recorded sound and using SystemSoundID to play an existing binary, I'd like to synthesise it. Partially, that's because I want to be able to play the sound continuously (e.g. when the user's finger is on the screen) instead of a one-off sound sample.

If I wanted to synthesise a Middle A+1 (A4) (440Hz), I can calculate a sine wave using sin(); what I don't know is how to arrange those bits into a packet which CoreAudio can then play. Most of the tutorials that exist on the net are concerned with simply playing existing binaries.

Can anyone help me with a simple synthesised sine sound wave at 440Hz?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want to do it probably to setup an AudioQueue. It allows you to fill a buffer with synthesized audio data in a callback. You would setup the AudeioQueue to run in a new thread as such:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 16384
#define BUFFER_COUNT 3
static AudioQueueRef audioQueue;
void SetupAudioQueue() {
    OSStatus err = noErr;
    // Setup the audio device.
    AudioStreamBasicDescription deviceFormat;
    deviceFormat.mSampleRate = 44100;
    deviceFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    deviceFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;
    deviceFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
    deviceFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    deviceFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
    deviceFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    deviceFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    deviceFormat.mReserved = 0;
    // Create a new output AudioQueue for the device.
    err = AudioQueueNewOutput(&deviceFormat, AudioQueueCallback, NULL,
                              CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes,
                              0, &audioQueue);
    // Allocate buffers for the AudioQueue, and pre-fill them.
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_COUNT; ++i) {
        AudioQueueBufferRef mBuffer;
        err = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(audioQueue, BUFFER_SIZE, mBuffer);
        if (err != noErr) break;
        AudioQueueCallback(NULL, audioQueue, mBuffer);
    }
    if (err == noErr) err = AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, NULL);
    if (err == noErr) CFRunLoopRun();
  }
```

You callback method AudioQueueCallback will then be called whenever the AudioQueue needs more data. Implement with something like:

```
void AudioQueueCallback(void* inUserData, AudioQueueRef inAQ,
                        AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer) {
    void* pBuffer = inBuffer->mAudioData;
    UInt32 bytes = inBuffer->mAudioDataBytesCapacity;
    // Write max <bytes> bytes of audio to <pBuffer>
    outBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize = actualNumberOfBytesWritten
    err = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(audioQueue, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct. You shouldn't be calling AudioQueueCallback in the allocation loop. I don't believe the description is setup correct, either.

Plus, you should be calling AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, nil) instead of this odd way. Look at the AudioUnit Framework instead.

Comment: @thefaj: I believe you are the one who is incorrect. This example is taken from my app SC68 Player (http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/sc68-player/id295290413?mt=8), where I have originally taken the code for audio replay from Apple's example iPhone app SpeakHere (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SpeakHere/), look at the AQPlayer.mm file.

Full source code for SC68 Player is available (http://www.peylow.se/sc68player.html).

Comment: Your example is missing AudioQueueStart() which is how the AudioQueueCallback should be called.

Comment: You forgot to check the error return of `AudioQueueNewOutput`.

Comment: Gods... I am regretting that I took actual code and tried to downsize it for an answer... I should probably just written some pseudocode and added a link to Apple's docs.

Comment: I think it's useful to see code get corrected. I'm not saying be sloppy but perfect code can sometimes hide the complexity of actually using some framework. This way we get to see how things could go wrong and how to fix them.

Answer (score 3):

Davide Vosti's link to http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2008/Dec/msg00173.html no longer works, since Apple lists seem to be unresponsive. Here is Google's cache for completeness.

```
//
//  AudioUnitTestAppDelegate.m
//  AudioUnitTest
//
//  Created by Marc Vaillant on 11/25/08.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2008. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AudioUnitTestAppDelegate.h"
#include <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>
//#include "MachTimer.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define kOutputBus 0
#define kInputBus 1
#define SAMPLE_RATE 44100

vector<int> _pcm;
int _index;

@implementation AudioUnitTestAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

void generateTone(
                vector<int>& pcm, 
                int freq, 
                double lengthMS, 
                int sampleRate, 
                double riseTimeMS, 
                double gain)
{
  int numSamples = ((double) sampleRate) * lengthMS / 1000.;
  int riseTimeSamples = ((double) sampleRate) * riseTimeMS / 1000.;

  if(gain > 1.)
    gain = 1.;
  if(gain < 0.)
    gain = 0.;

  pcm.resize(numSamples);

  for(int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i)
  {
    double value = sin(2. * M_PI * freq * i / sampleRate);
    if(i < riseTimeSamples)
      value *= sin(i * M_PI / (2.0 * riseTimeSamples));
    if(i > numSamples - riseTimeSamples - 1)
      value *= sin(2. * M_PI * (i - (numSamples - riseTimeSamples) + riseTimeSamples)/ (4. * riseTimeSamples));

    pcm[i] = (int) (value * 32500.0 * gain);
    pcm[i] += (pcm[i]<<16);
  }

}

static OSStatus playbackCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData) 
{    
    cout<<"index = "<<_index<<endl;
    cout<<"numBuffers = "<<ioData->mNumberBuffers<<endl;

    int totalNumberOfSamples = _pcm.size();
    for(UInt32 i = 0; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; ++i)
    {
      int samplesLeft = totalNumberOfSamples - _index;
      int numSamples = ioData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize / 4;
      if(samplesLeft > 0)
      {
        if(samplesLeft < numSamples)
        {
          memcpy(ioData->mBuffers[i].mData, &_pcm[_index], samplesLeft * 4);
          _index += samplesLeft;
          memset((char*) ioData->mBuffers[i].mData + samplesLeft * 4, 0, (numSamples - samplesLeft) * 4) ;
        }
        else
        {
          memcpy(ioData->mBuffers[i].mData, &_pcm[_index], numSamples * 4) ;
          _index += numSamples;
        }
      }
      else
        memset(ioData->mBuffers[i].mData, 0, ioData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize);
    }

    return noErr;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{    
  //generate pcm tone  freq = 800, duration = 1s, rise/fall time = 5ms

  generateTone(_pcm, 800, 1000, SAMPLE_RATE, 5, 0.8);
  _index = 0;

  OSStatus status;
  AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;

  // Describe audio component
  AudioComponentDescription desc;
  desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
  desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
  desc.componentFlags = 0;
  desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
  desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

  // Get component
  AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

  // Get audio units
  status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &audioUnit);
  //checkStatus(status);

  UInt32 flag = 1;
  // Enable IO for playback
  status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                  kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                  kOutputBus,
                  &flag, 
                  sizeof(flag));
  //checkStatus(status);

  // Describe format

  AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
  audioFormat.mSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE;
  audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
  audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
  audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
  audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
  audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
  audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
  audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 4;

  // Apply format

  status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                  kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                  kOutputBus, 
                  &audioFormat, 
                  sizeof(audioFormat));
//  checkStatus(status);

  // Set output callback
  AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
  callbackStruct.inputProc = playbackCallback;
  callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;
  status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                  kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
                  kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                  kOutputBus,
                  &callbackStruct, 
                  sizeof(callbackStruct));

  // Initialize
  status = AudioUnitInitialize(audioUnit);

  // Start playing

  status = AudioOutputUnitStart(audioUnit);

  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: I would have added it as a comment to Davide's question, but there's a 600 character limit for comments.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the audio technologies allow for data to be passed in instead of a sound file.  AVAudioPlayer, for example, has:

```
-initWithData:error:
Initializes and returns an audio player for playing a designated memory buffer.

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)outError
```

However, I am not sure how you would pass in a data ptr, start the sound, and then keeping it looping by passing in other data ptrs, or repeating the same, etc.